# How to fit gameobjects to any phone in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I making a game for phones but i noticed that in other phones the game doesnt fit.
How to fit gameobjects to any phone?
maybe there is rect transform for normal gameobjects?

i tried to add rect transform to normal gameobjects.but i realized that is work only with UI.

Comment: using the UI canvas you can always make that fit..